# Why is the application name defined in code not taken to display in RUNNING Applications in YARN UI?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

This is the relevant part of my Spark application where I set the application's name using `appName`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object sample extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.
    builder().
    appName("Cortex-Batch").  // <-- application name
    enableHiveSupport().
    getOrCreate()
```

I check the name of the Spark application in the Hadoop YARN cluster under RUNNING Applications and don't see the name I defined in the code. Why?

I use `spark-submit` with a property file using `--properties-file` as follows:

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --class com.jpmc.cortex.LoadCortexDataLake \
  --verbose \
  --properties-file /home/e707698/cortex-batch.properties \
  --jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.‌​jar,/usr/hdp/current‌​/spark-client/lib/da‌​tanucleus-core-3.2.1‌​0.jar,/usr/hdp/curre‌​nt/spark-client/lib/‌​datanucleus-rdbms-3.‌​2.9.jar \
  /home/e707698/cortex-data-lake-batch.jar "/tmp/clickfiles1" "cortex_dev.xpo_click1"
```

Instead, the app name given in property file is taken. I tried to remove the property from the properties file, but then the name is the full class name of the Spark application, i.e. `/com/jpmc/cortex/LoadCortexDataLake`.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Where do you check that _"I don't get the app name defined here."_? What's the property file and the property in _"app name given in property file is taken"_? How do you submit the Spark app?

Comment: Can you check if `--name` on command line for `spark-submit` would make any difference? Can you take a screenshot of the page with the name from the web UI and include in the question?

Answer (score 0):

`--name` works.  I am now able to see what I give in --name with spark-submit in Yarn Running applications.

Answer (score 0):

When we run spark in cluster mode Yarn application is created before sparkcontext is created, hence we need to give app name as --name in SparkSubmit command.
In client mode we can set the app name in the program like spark.appname("Default App Name")